# Passing an empty array from function to main

Tags: c

I am writing a function, which takes some char array as an input from the `main()`. This function returns pointer to char. There are three problems:

1. If everything goes as it should, this function should return a pointer to the  subarray of the passed array. Since `main()` needs to be able to access this subarray, I can use `malloc` in the function to create this global subarray.
2. I need the function to pass an empty char array `{}` to `main()`.
3. To do the error checking, I need to pass `NULL` pointer. I only have question about the second issue. How do I pass pointer to the empty character array `{}` to the `main()` ?

I don't know if `malloc` will be helpful here.

`**EDIT**`:

Ok, I think I caused some confusion. Let me specify the exact problem. I am writing
a function of the form `char * test(char * a, int start, int end, int len)` . Now a typical
input to this would be an array like `{'a', 'b', 'c'}` for the array, `start = 0` , `end = 3` , `len  = 3`. `len` here is the length of the input array. `start` is the starting position. In this example, its `0`, which is beginning of the array. Now the `end` value says that start at the `start` value and take `end` no of elements from the `start` value. In this example, it will mean , start at `'a'` and take 3 elements from there, i.e. `'a'` , `'b'`, and `'c'`. And form a new array with such a selection. Here we get original array back. So let `a[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}`. Then `test(a , 0 , 3 , 3)` will return a pointer to
`{'a', 'b', 'c'}`. Likewise, `test(a , 0 , 2 , 3)` will return a pointer to `{'a', 'b'}` and `test(a , 1 , 2 , 3)` will return a pointer to `{'b', 'c'}`.
         Now I want the function to return a `NULL` pointer if `(start < 0) || (end < 0) || (0 == len) || (start+ end > len)`. So in the following situations the function returns a `NULL` pointer.
`test(a , 0 , 4 , 3)`
`test(a , 1 , 3 , 3)`
`test(a , 2 , 2 , 3)`
`test(a , 3 , 1 , 3)`
`test(a , -1 , 2 , 3)`
`test(a , -1 , -2 , 3)`

and if `a[] = {}`  then `test(a , 0 , 1 , 3)` should return `NULL`. I got this figured. Now if the `end` value is `0`, I want to function to return the pointer to the empty array `{}`. Function should not modify the original array.

`EDIT NO 2:`

I am doing sample problem 3 from http://admin.cs.mum.edu/Pretest/sampletest.htm. Hope that helps...

Comment: can u post some code for simplicity!!!

Comment: How will the main function know that the array you return is empty?

Comment: Couldn't you return the subarray by index reference instead? In other words, return the start and end indices from the original array, instead of creating a brand new one.

Comment: `How do I pass pointer to the empty character array` - how do you define "empty"? Is it uninitialized? Is it full of 0's?

Comment: There are no "empty arrays" in C, the notation `{}` doesn't mean anything that can be desribed using those words. In other words, you're not making a lot of sense, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can return structure which will contain the pointer to the address & length which will be filled inside your function.

```
struct ret_me
{
    char *p;
    int len;
}

.....

main()
{
    .......
    struct ret_me xxx;
    xxx=your_fun(...);
    if(xxx.len == 0)
    ...array is empty...
    ..........

}
```

Comment: +1 for adding sense to the discussion of array lengths, and also for using struct return.